# Rainfall challenge: how big are the basins?

Tags: java, community-challenge, junit

### [August 2016 challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6911/71574)

> #### The [Rainfall Challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/38500/71574)
>
> Problem description is copied verbatim from the linked Code Review
>   question:
>
> > **Problem Statement**
> >
> > A group of farmers has some elevation data, and we're going to help
> >     them understand how rainfall flows over their farmland.
> >
> > We'll represent the land as a two-dimensional array of altitudes and
> >     use the following model, based on the idea that water flows downhill:
> >
> > If a cell’s four neighboring cells all have higher altitudes, we call
> >     this cell a sink; water collects in sinks.
> >
> > Otherwise, water will flow to the neighboring cell with the lowest
> >     altitude. If a cell is not a sink, you may assume it has a unique
> >     lowest neighbor and that this neighbor will be lower than the cell.
> >
> > Cells that drain into the same sink – directly or indirectly – are
> >     said to be part of the same basin.
> >
> > Your challenge is to partition the map into basins. In particular,
> >     given a map of elevations, your code should partition the map into
> >     basins and output the sizes of the basins, in descending order.
> >
> > Assume the elevation maps are square. Input will begin with a line
> >     with one integer, S, the height (and width) of the map. The next S
> >     lines will each contain a row of the map, each with S integers – the
> >     elevations of the S cells in the row. Some farmers have small land
> >     plots such as the examples below, while some have larger plots.
> >     However, in no case will a farmer have a plot of land larger than S =
> >     5000.
> >
> > Your code should output a space-separated list of the basin sizes, in
> >     descending order. (Trailing spaces are ignored.)
>
> For examples see the the linked question :)

#### RainfallChallenge.java

```
public class RainfallChallenge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            Grid grid = new Grid(stdin.nextInt());
            grid.read(stdin);

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            for (int basinSize : grid.solve()) {
                output.append(basinSize);
                output.append(' ');
            }
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }

}
```

#### Grid.java

```
public class Grid {

    Cell[][] grid;

    public Grid(int size) {
        grid = new Cell[size][size];
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
                grid[row][column] = new Cell(grid, row, column);
            }
        }
    }

    public void read(Scanner stdin) {
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
                grid[row][column].setHeight(stdin.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }

    public void test(int[][] heights) {
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
                grid[row][column].setHeight(heights[row][column]);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> solve() {
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
                grid[row][column].findSink();
            }
        }

        Map<Cell, List<Cell>> basins = new HashMap<>();
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
                Cell end = grid[row][column].getSink();

                List<Cell> cells = basins.get(end);
                if (cells == null) {
                    cells = new ArrayList<>();
                    basins.put(end, cells);
                }

                cells.add(grid[row][column]);
            }
        }

        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Cell> basin : basins.values()) {
            results.add(basin.size());
        }

        Collections.sort(results, Collections.reverseOrder());

        return results;
    }

}
```

#### Cell.java

```
public class Cell {

    private final int row;
    private final int column;
    private int height;
    private Cell next = this;
    private Cell sink = next;
    private Cell[][] grid;

    public Cell(Cell[][] grid, int row, int column) {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        next = this;
        sink = next;
    }

    public Cell getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    private void setNextIfLower(Cell candidate) {
        if (candidate.getHeight() < next.getHeight()) {
            next = candidate;
        }
    }

    public Cell getSink() {
        return sink;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    // package visibility is intentional
    void findSink() {
        _findSink();
    }

    private Cell _findSink() {
        // if we've already updated the sink, just return it
        if (sink != this) {
            return sink;
        }

        if (row > 0) {
            setNextIfLower(grid[row - 1][column]);
        }

        if (column > 0) {
            setNextIfLower(grid[row][column - 1]);
        }

        if (row + 1 < grid.length) {
            setNextIfLower(grid[row + 1][column]);
        }

        if (column + 1 < grid[row].length) {
            setNextIfLower(grid[row][column + 1]);
        }

        if (next != this) {
            sink = next._findSink();
        }

        return sink;
    }

}
```

#### RainfallTest.java

```
public class RainfallTest {

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        int[][] heights = {{1, 5, 2},
                           {2, 4, 7},
                           {3, 6, 9}};
        Grid grid = new Grid(heights.length);
        grid.test(heights);
        List<Integer> basinSizes = grid.solve();
        assert(basinSizes.size() == 2);
        assert(basinSizes.get(0) == 7);
        assert(basinSizes.get(1) == 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        int[][] heights = {{10}};
        Grid grid = new Grid(heights.length);
        grid.test(heights);
        List<Integer> basinSizes = grid.solve();
        assert(basinSizes.size() == 1);
        assert(basinSizes.get(0) == 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test5() {
        int[][] heights = {{1, 0, 2, 5, 8},
                           {2, 3, 4, 7, 9},
                           {3, 5, 7, 8, 9},
                           {1, 2, 5, 4, 3},
                           {3, 3, 5, 2, 1}};
        Grid grid = new Grid(heights.length);
        grid.test(heights);
        List<Integer> basinSizes = grid.solve();
        assert(basinSizes.size() == 3);
        assert(basinSizes.get(0) == 11);
        assert(basinSizes.get(1) == 7);
        assert(basinSizes.get(2) == 7);
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        int[][] heights = {{0, 2, 1, 3},
                           {2, 1, 0, 4},
                           {3, 3, 3, 3},
                           {5, 5, 2, 1}};
        Grid grid = new Grid(heights.length);
        grid.test(heights);
        List<Integer> basinSizes = grid.solve();
        assert(basinSizes.size() == 3);
        assert(basinSizes.get(0) == 7);
        assert(basinSizes.get(1) == 5);
        assert(basinSizes.get(2) == 4);
    }

}
```

The `jUnit` tests are based on the examples from the linked question.

Comment: Your tests seem to invoke the wrong asserts. You call the Java `assert(...)` method which only is activated if you pass `-ea` on program start. I guess you mean something like `Assert.assertTrue(condition)` or `Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual)`. Also, name your test method something more expressive then testN where N is something between 1 and 99999

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tests - Focus and naming**

Since you had provided them, the first bit of your code I looked at were your tests.  As has been pointed out by  @Roman Vottner, their names are not very descriptive.  `test1`, `test2` etc tell the reader nothing about the scenario that is being tested.  I'm guessing that they should be called something like `test5x5GridContains3Basins`.

The tests themselves are quite concise, although again as has been pointed out by @Roman, you're not calling `assert.assertEquals` which is what I'd expect.  All of your tests are also validating all of the basins in the returned list.  This is a good way to test a whole scenario, however it doesn't help you to know if you're testing all of the edge cases.  Having more tests that validate only a single thing can be more descriptive (this also makes it easier to name the tests).  For example:

```
`test5x5GridDetectsSingleCentralBasin`
`test4x4GridDetectsLowerRightCornerBasin`
`test3x3GridDetectsTopLeftCornerBasin`
```

Tests - Writing code for tests / testable code

Your `Grid` method exposes two public methods for populating the grids initial values:

```
public void read(Scanner stdin) 
public void test(int[][] heights)
```

The first method `read` is called from the Challenge class and the second `test` is called from your test classes.  This duplication is caused by `Grid` knowing how to read information from the user.  It would be better to only expose a single method, possibly `populateGrid(int [][] heights)` or `populateGrid(List<Integer>)` and have another class responsible (or the main method) for constructing the array from user input.  This prevents the need the `Grid` class to differentiate between when it's being called properly and when it's being called under test.  This also removes one of the confusing aspects of your unit tests where you do this:

```
grid.test(heights);
List<Integer> basinSizes = grid.solve();
```

Having the method named `test` makes it appear like you're expecting `grid` to test itself, then solve itself.  Whereas with a different name it feels more expressive:

```
grid.populateGrid(heights);
List<Integer> basinSizes = grid.solve();
```

**Cell**

The responsibilities of your Cell class are confusing.  It seems strange for a class called Cell to contain an array of Cells.  I also found the field `next` particularly unexpected.  What does it mean to be the `next` cell?

**Overall**

That said, overall despite some of the naming quirks and distributed responsibilities I did find your code to be mostly expressive and easy to follow.  I particularly liked the way you had constructed the grids within your tests, so that they were laid out like a map to be processed.

Comment: The `next` cell is the one to which water flows next.  If you follow the chain of `next` cells, you'll eventually reach the sink.  Note that a sink is its own sink and next cell.  What would you expect this to be called?

Comment: @mdfst13 perhaps something like downhillcell, or drain (water drains towards the sink) would help convey what it is modeling. The main problem I have with with next is that it's used so often in loops and collections that it could mean (next to process), or (next link in chain)  so on its own it is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 7):

This code snippet appears several times in your code:

```
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
```

And I think it's because there's a conflict of responsibilities about where the location of a cell is stored. In some sense, the used data structure (a nested array)

```
Cell[][] grid;
```

contains the 2D location of each cell already. But each cell also stores its position as member variables:

```
public class Cell {

    private final int row;
    private final int column;
```

This seems to be duplicated logic that is not synced.

> **Hyperbolic example** interlude not applicable to the code at hand: imagine you swap two `Cell` objects in `grid`, who takes care of updating the `private` properties that are ...`final`!? - ooops. The data is stored redundantly and only one instance can be altered.

From `Grid.java`'s point of view, the solution is simple: Use a more general data structure like `ArrayList` for example, that allows you to "iterate over all elements" (which is what you are really doing anyway) with something like a for-in loop. If any action in the loop body requires the position of the cell, it can retrieve it from the cell. This would reduce the necessity for the double `for` loop to the construction of the cells. I guess Streams could also come in handy to make things even more simple.

**However** here's this other dependency on the nested array in `Cell.java` itself, namely the members:

```
private Cell _findSink()
// and
private void setNextIfLower(Cell candidate)
```

With the approach outlined above, there's no overall data structure that dictates any structure (except listing all `Cell` objects), which means that each `Cell` object has to store references to its neighbours itself. The consequence of this approach is that the whole thing is stored as a graph (which happens to be a grid) with each `Cell` being a node.

Comment: You could even have a List of Cell arrays and just iterate over each using a for-each loop