# Water flowing swiftly over farmland – The August 2016 Community Challenge

Tags: swift, community-challenge, swift3

This is my attempt to solve the [August 2016 Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6872/august-2016-community-challenge) in Swift. I tried to implement the [algorithm
described by @200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/38526/35991):

> 1. Each `Cell` keeps track of which `Basin` it belongs to; each `Cell` is initially assume to be in its own `Basin`.  Each `Basin` has a
>      `sink`, or lowest `Cell`, which acts as a "representative element" of
>      the `Basin`, as well as a member count.  `Topography` keeps track of
>      all `Basin`s.
> 2. For each `Basin`, find lowest of the sink's neighbours.  If the lowest is not already a member of this `Basin`, transfer its cells
>      into the lowest neighbour's `Basin`, and notify `Topography` that the
>      higher basin no longer exists.
> 3. Repeat step 2 until no further action is necessary.
> 4. Have `Topography` enumerate the `Basin`s and their counts.

The code is Swift 3 and requires Xcode 8 beta 4.

**Cell.swift**

```
import Swift

class Cell {
    let elevation: Int
    var lowerCell: Cell?
    weak var basin: Basin?

    init(elevation: Int) {
        self.elevation = elevation
    }

    /// Compare the elevation of the (currently) lowest neighbor with that of
    /// the other cell, and update `lowerCell` if necessary. Returns `true`
    /// if other cell was lower, and `false` otherwise.
    @discardableResult
    func updateLowerCell(with other: Cell) -> Bool {
        if other.elevation < (lowerCell?.elevation) ?? elevation {
            lowerCell = other
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**Basin.swift**

```
import Swift

/// A basin consists of a "sink" and zero or more cells which eventually flow
/// into the sink.
class Basin {
    var cells: [Cell]
    var sink: Cell

    init(cell: Cell) {
        cells = [cell]
        sink = cell
        cell.basin = self
    }

    func join(with other: Basin) {
        precondition(other !== self, "Basin must not be joined with itself")
        for cell in other.cells {
            cell.basin = self
        }
        cells.append(contentsOf: other.cells)
        other.cells.removeAll()
    }
}
```

**Topography.swift**

```
import Swift

/// A topography is a collection of basins. The union of all the
/// basins cells is always the complete grid.
struct Topography {
    var basins: [Basin]

    /// Create topography from a sequence of cells. Initially, each basin
    /// consists of a single cell.
    init<S: Sequence>(cells: S)
        where S.Iterator.Element == Cell {
            basins = cells.map(Basin.init)
    }

    /// Create topography from 2D elevation map.
    init(elevationData: [[Int]]) {
        // Create `[[Cell]]` array from `elevationData`.
        let grid = elevationData.map { levelRow in
            levelRow.map(Cell.init)
        }

        // Find the lowest neighbor for each cell: left/right ...
        for gridRow in grid {
            for (leftCell, rightCell) in zip(gridRow, gridRow.dropFirst()) {
                if !leftCell.updateLowerCell(with: rightCell) {
                    rightCell.updateLowerCell(with: leftCell)
                }
            }
        }
        // ... and top/down.
        for (upperRow, lowerRow) in zip(grid, grid.dropFirst()) {
            for (upperCell, lowerCell) in zip(upperRow, lowerRow) {
                if !upperCell.updateLowerCell(with: lowerCell) {
                    lowerCell.updateLowerCell(with: upperCell)
                }
            }
        }

        self.init(cells: grid.flatten())
    }

    /// Join each basin with the next one that it is flowing into.
    mutating func joinBasins() {
        basins = basins.filter { basin in
            if let otherBasin = basin.sink.lowerCell?.basin, otherBasin !== basin {
                otherBasin.join(with: basin)
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    /// Sizes of all basins, sorted in decreasing order.
    func basinSizes() -> [Int] {
        return basins.map { $0.cells.count }.sorted(by: >)
    }
}
```

**RainfallSolver.swift**

```
import Swift

/// Wrapper type with a single static method to solve the Rainfall problem.
struct RainfallSolver {

    static func solve(elevationData: [[Int]]) -> [Int] {
        var topo = Topography(elevationData: elevationData)
        topo.joinBasins()
        return topo.basinSizes()
    }
}
```

The main program in **main.swift** which reads the elevation data
(as in the specified input format) from standard input and prints
the solution to standard output.

```
import Foundation

func readIntegers() -> [Int] {
    let line = readLine(strippingNewline: true)!
    let comps = line.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespaces).filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    return comps.map { Int($0)! }
}

func readElevationData() -> [[Int]] {
    let dimension = readIntegers().first!
    let elevationData = (0..<dimension).map { _ in readIntegers() }
    return elevationData
}

let elevationData = readElevationData()
let solution = RainfallSolver.solve(elevationData: elevationData)
// Print solution as space-separated list:
print(solution.map(String.init).joined(separator: " "))
```

Finally, unit tests with the four given examples from
[Rainfall challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38500/rainfall-challenge)
in
**RainfallTests.swift.** All tests pass.

```
import XCTest

class RainfallTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample1() {
        let solution = RainfallSolver.solve(elevationData: [
            [ 1, 5, 2 ],
            [ 2, 4, 7 ],
            [ 3, 6, 9 ]
            ])
        XCTAssertEqual(solution, [ 7, 2 ])
    }

    func testExample2() {
        let solution = RainfallSolver.solve(elevationData: [
            [ 1 ]
            ])
        XCTAssertEqual(solution, [ 1 ])
    }

    func testExample3() {
        let solution = RainfallSolver.solve(elevationData: [
            [ 1, 0, 2, 5, 8 ],
            [ 2, 3, 4, 7, 9 ],
            [ 3, 5, 7, 8, 9 ],
            [ 1, 2, 5, 4, 3 ],
            [ 3, 3, 5, 2, 1 ]
            ])
        XCTAssertEqual(solution, [ 11, 7, 7 ])
    }

    func testExample4() {
        let solution = RainfallSolver.solve(elevationData: [
            [ 0, 2, 1, 3 ],
            [ 2, 1, 0, 4 ],
            [ 3, 3, 3, 3 ],
            [ 5, 5, 2, 1 ]
            ])
        XCTAssertEqual(solution, [ 7, 5, 4 ])
    }
}
```

**Remarks:**

- `Cell` and `Basin` are defined as *classes* because there are references between instances of these types. In particular, the  reference from a cell to its containing basin is a weak reference to avoid retain cycles. All other types are *structs* (value types).
- A cell does not know its coordinates. The cells are stored in a 2D `grid` only temporarily in `init(elevationData: [[Int]])`, in order to determine the lowest neighbours. After that, the actual geometry is not used anymore.
- In `joinBasins()`, each of the initial (single-cell) basins is  visited exactly once, and potentially joined with a "lower basin" as described in step #2 of the algorithm.

  In the first version of this program, I repeated step #2 until no more basins are joined. However, after observing that the second pass never joined additional basins, I convinced myself that a single pass is sufficient. This was verified with the given examples and additional randomly created grids.
- `readElevationData()` in main.swift expects the data in the specified input format and will crash otherwise. However, an arbitrary amount of whitespace is accepted as separator between the integers and not just a single space character, this turned out to be convenient for my test cases. A detailed error reporting is omitted.
- The code actually works with rectangular maps, not only with 
  quadratic maps.

Answer (score 4):

I think this code is great. Using weak references to refer to a `Basin` is a great way to prevent retain cycles with automatic reference counting. One suggestion I have is to make `Topography` a class, because it refers to a class. Other suggestions are in the code, marked with "CR". You can use this snippet of code:

````swift
/// A topography is a collection of basins. The union of all the
/// basins cells is always the complete grid.
class Topography {
    var basins: [Basin]

    /// Create topography from a sequence of cells. Initially, each basin
    /// consists of a single cell.
    init<S: Sequence>(cells: S)
        where S.Element == Cell { // CR: `S.Iterator.Element` is the same as `S.Element`
            basins = cells.map(Basin.init)
    }

    /// Create topography from 2D elevation map.
    convenience init(elevationData: [[Int]]) { // CR: This calls the designated initializer, so it should be a convenience initializer.
        // Create `[[Cell]]` array from `elevationData`.
        let grid = elevationData.map { $0.map(Cell.init) } // CR: `levelRow in` clutters code, implicit names are better for simple lambdas.

        // Find the lowest neighbor for each cell: left/right ...
        for gridRow in grid {
            for (leftCell, rightCell) in zip(gridRow, gridRow.dropFirst()) {
                if !leftCell.updateLowerCell(with: rightCell) {
                    rightCell.updateLowerCell(with: leftCell)
                }
            }
        }
        // ... and top/down.
        for (upperRow, lowerRow) in zip(grid, grid.dropFirst()) {
            for (upperCell, lowerCell) in zip(upperRow, lowerRow) {
                if !upperCell.updateLowerCell(with: lowerCell) {
                    lowerCell.updateLowerCell(with: upperCell)
                }
            }
        }

        self.init(cells: grid.flatten())
    }

    /// Join each basin with the next one that it is flowing into.
    func joinBasins() -> Bool { // CR: classes are mutable by default, also, included return type
        basins = basins.filter { basin in
            if let otherBasin = basin.sink.lowerCell?.basin, otherBasin !== basin {
                otherBasin.join(with: basin)
                return false
            }
            return true // CR: Removed else, `return` exits
        }
    }

    /// Sizes of all basins, sorted in decreasing order.
    func basinSizes() -> [Int] {
        return basins.map { $0.cells.count }.sorted(by: >)
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Cell and Basin are defined as classes because there are references between instances of these types, but that is not the case for Topography. I don't see yet why Topography should be made a class instead of a struct. A general rule (I think) is: use value types (structs) unless there is a reason not to do so. “... because it refers to a class” is not sufficient reason IMO.